# Is there a utility similar to Better Touch Tool

Tags: software-installation, tools

Is there a linux utility similar to [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) on macOS.

I want to customise keyboard shortcuts and mouse buttons to specific desktop/app interactions. Ideally it would work on Mate, but I'd be happy to switch DE/WM if such a tool only worked on a specific one.

Comment: See https://alternativeto.net/software/bettertouchtool/?platform=linux